# Typescript confusing definition with "new()" and constructors

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to use a popular javascript library called `marked` in a `Typescript` application, through an `angular` plugin called `angular-marked`.

[marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked)
[angular-marked](https://github.com/Hypercubed/angular-marked)

`marked` has a `.d.ts` file on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/marked), so I included that.

Now, the problem is that `angular-marked` has a new function called `setRenderer`, and it takes in an object literal that is supposed to match the `marked.Renderer`. That's not a problem in plain javascript.

`setRenderer` is not defined in the typescript definition, but `MarkedRenderer` is, which is (theoretically) the parameter type going through the function. So I tried to just make my own interface to declare it, like so;

```
interface MarkedStatic {
   setRenderer(renderer: MarkedRenderer): MarkedStatic;
}
```

That seemed simple enough. But when I try to use this, I get all kinds of nonsense. For example, I wanted to simply override the way it outputs `blockquote`. In normal javascript, it is this simple;

```
$markedProvider.setRenderer({
    blockquote:(quote: string): string => {
        return 'customized output';
    }
});
```

But in typescript, I get the error...

> Argument of type '{ blockquote: (quote: string) => string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MarkedRenderer'. Property 'code' is missing in type '{ blockquote: (quote: string) => string; }'.

That seemed a bit confusing to me, but I assumed it meant I needed to create a new renderer using the `new` keyword.

So I try...

> var r = new marked.Renderer();

And I'm told it doesn't exist. Even with the `marked.js` library clearly imported and working.

I eventually "forced" this to work by creating a new interface that sets every function as optional, like this;

```
interface IMarkdownProvider extends MarkedStatic {
    setRenderer?(renderer?: IMarkedRenderer);
}

interface IMarkedRenderer {
    code?(code: string, language: string): string;
    blockquote?(quote: string): string;
    html?(html: string): string;
    heading?(text: string, level: number, raw: string): string;
    hr?(): string;
    list?(body: string, ordered: boolean): string;
    listitem?(text: string): string;
    paragraph?(text: string): string;
    table?(header: string, body: string): string;
    tablerow?(content: string): string;
    tablecell?(content: string, flags: {
        header: boolean,
        align: string
    }): string;
    strong?(text: string): string;
    em?(text: string): string;
    codespan?(code: string): string;
    br?(): string;
    del?(text: string): string;
    link?(href: string, title: string, text: string): string;
    image?(href: string, title: string, text: string): string;
    text?(text: string): string;
}
```

But I would really like to understand and reach a more organic solution. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer you solution but you could try something like this if you have a mixin function available and a reference to a default renderer:

```
let mixin : <A,B>(a: A, b: B) => A & B;

interface IMarkdownProvider {
    setRenderer?(renderer?: IMarkedRenderer);
}

interface IMarkedRenderer {
    code(code: string, language: string): string;
    br(): string;
    del(text: string): string;
}

let provider: IMarkdownProvider;
let defaultRenderer = <IMarkedRenderer>{};

provider.setRenderer(mixin(defaultRenderer, {br: () => "br"}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your fix to mark all the fields of `IMarkedRenderer` as optional is correct, as is your fix to add an additional `setRenderer` method to `MarkedStatic`

Based on the documentation in the repo, it doesn't look like you should be adding `new` anywhere. The instance you need is already provided by the DI injector and should be sufficient.